# How to return response/promises in forEach that stores into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, foreach, promise

I've read over a bunch of similar types of questions, but can't get it to work in my own use case. I'm scraping Twitter and using the Twitter module.

```
const Twitter = require("twitter");

var i = 0;
var store = [];

var clients = [
    new Twitter({
        consumer_key: "",
        consumer_secret: "",
        access_token_key: "",
        access_token_secret: "",
    }),
    new Twitter({
        consumer_key: "",
        consumer_secret: "",
        access_token_key: "",
        access_token_secret: "",
    }),
]

const users = [
    'twitteruser1',
    'twitteruser2',
]

users.forEach(function (user) {
    clients[0].get("statuses/user_timeline", { screen_name: user, count: 5 }, (error, tweets, response) => {
        try {
            tweets.forEach(function(tweet){
                store.push(tweet.id_str)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
})
```

I need this to run before the rest of my code, which of course it won't without proper promise resolving. I couldn't get this to work however, despite looking over all the resolve all promise stuff I read over.

Here's the next snippet of code that shows how the array is being used:

```
clients.forEach(function (client) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            client.get("statuses/user_timeline", { screen_name: users[i % users.length], count: 1}, (error, tweets, response) => {
                try {
                    if (!store.some(found => found == tweets[0].id_str)) {
                        ... etc ...
```

Basically stores last 5 of each users tweets, then checks to see if they send one that doesn't already exist in the array "store" (new tweet), then actions on it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to move some things into async functions and then use `Promise.all` to resolve those things before going forward. never used the twitter package so I'm unsure as to a specific solution

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { setInterval(() => { ...` this looks like a _really_ bad idea to me.

Comment: i have to stagger 20 sets of different twitter api keys..
due to rate limits, here's what I did: 
`}, 1000)}, (1000 / clients.length) * (clients.indexOf(client) % clients.length))`
is there a more reliable way of doing this? I have to stagger 20 requests at 50 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` is your best bet for executing multiple async tasks in parallel with the results of each coming back in an Array:

```
const Twitter = require("twitter");

function getLatestUserTweets() { 
  // This will be an array of arrays
  return Promise.all(users.map(user => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    clients[0].get(
      "statuses/user_timeline", { screen_name: user, count: 5 },
      (error, tweets, response) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(tweets)
    );
  })));
}
```

Or hopefully the Twitter API has an option to use Promises directly so you can simplify further without needing to wrap in a `new Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

Using async operations in forEach loops won't really play nicely, as you apparently have seen. For that I can suggest the following code from [this lovely article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404). You might understand how it works a bit better if you read the article quickly.

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

You can then call this function as follows:

```
const start = async () => {
  await asyncForEach([1, 2, 3], async (num) => {
    await waitFor(50);
    console.log(num);
  });
  console.log('Done');
}

start();

// Result
// 1
// 2
// 3
// Done
```

Another possible solution is as suggested by Jhecht; the usage of Promise.all().